# How can I use Flash to remember user data?

Tags: mysql, flash

I am making a Flash game that stores user's statistics from previous sessions. I would also like to maintain some sort of leader board as well.

After I posted, I realized I was asking the wrong question. I feel that shared objects are the proper solution to this problem rather than using a database. Any further feedback for implementing shared objects is welcome.
Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Just a thought: What you describe looks like a very simple data model that might not even require MySQL, or any relational database, at all.  If you are dealing with data for just the current user at a time, you might want to use a local shared object, or a file based approach, instead.

Comment: This is useful feedback. I'm so used to relying on databases for persistence of information that I over-looked flashes built-in persistence. Thanks.

Comment: Just read your edit. Silly me. Oh well, maybe someone else will find my answer useful, so I'll leave it there. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dharmavir mentioned, you cannot process MySQL queries through Flash (AS*).

That said, its pretty easy to setup Flash to communicate with remote scripts, as it has the ability to POST/GET data through requests.

There are many tutorials on this.

First, write a simple script to input the data into the DB. I recommend using PHP (I think its the easiest to learn tbh).

If this is your first time performing queries with PHP, I also recommend using Prepared Statements instead of `mysql_*`.

Once you have your script setup, you can then move onto processing a request from your flash app to your script (which is also pretty easy).

I found a tutorial series on making a chat app with flash and PHP. The tutorial includes making requests to PHP scripts and inputting data to SQL DBs, so it should help you:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeWKauwFUEQ < This tutorial is split into many different videos. take a look at the suggestions to find the others.

Answer (score 2):

You can not directly query MySQL database table from Flash game, you must have some server-side technology backing you up for the job.

I would suggest using some PHP or Ruby - or whatever is easily available to you for the job.

Flash is going to be rendered on Client browser (as swf) and won't be in touch with server as it will be served as a static resource by the web browser.

I hope this reply will help you moving towards right direction.